# Check if specific column in csv file contains data

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I need to check if the third column of my row in a CSV file contains 2016.

My code so far:

```
    import csv
    import pandas
    from docutils.utils import column_indices
    from bsddb.dbtables import contains_metastrings
    file = open("Advertising.csv")

    #write new file
    c = csv.writer(open("boop.csv", "wb"))
    #read in original file
    readCSV = csv.reader(file,delimiter= ",")


    for row in readCSV :
        print "something"
        #if contains(2016)
        if readCSV.index_col(2).Contains('2016') :
            print "2016 spotted"
            c.writerow(row)
    
    file.close()
```

The line checking the third column is wrong and produces and error:

```
AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'index_col'
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What is the error produced ?

Comment: 'readCSV' object has no attribute 'index_col'

Comment: @LoïcG. seems I am using the index_col the wrong way?

Comment: In your code, it seems you use the `csv` module without importing it. `index_col` is an argument of the `pandas.read_csv()` function but you don't use it

Comment: Sorry,  I imported the csv module, just didnt copy it in properly.

Comment: @PurpleCoffee I guess instead of `readCSV.index_col(2)` it should be `row.index_col(2)`.

Comment: @LoïcG. So how would I use that to read the third column? Will I need to change the previous code also?

Comment: @VivekRai : No, `row` is a list and a list doesn't have a `index_col()` method. There is a mix between `pandas` and `csv` here

Comment: Yeah I wasnt sure how to just say check this column, if it contains something do this. But the answer below helped as well as your input thank you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `pandas` for this. `csv` module would be fine

```
import csv

with open("file.csv", "rb") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in csvreader:
        if "2016" in row[2]:
            print "2016 spotted"
```

Comment: Also, just realised how obvious this was since the rows are lists, and the columns are items in the rows.. ahhh

Comment: When you don't know, you can do `print row` to see what `row` is ;)

Comment: Yeah, it should have been obvious I know. :/

Comment: @Loïc G, is there a way to do this for every file in a directory? I am trying to check is 2 columns in 108 csv files have any empty values. Thanks

Comment: @geds133 Yes : you just need to iterate over those files. Take a look about `os` module