# How do you search a CSV file in python?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.2

I am trying to create a CSV file with two headings:

```
Name Score
```

and then underneath input the name and score. this is so that if the program was run again it would find that name and score was already implemented and not run it again and instead skip that process and just proceed to enter the name and score. here is my current code below. any advice or help i greatly welcome:

```
filename = Class_Name + ".csv" #have already defined filename earlier

def excel_search():
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file_data:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file_data, ("Score"))
        if i not in reader:
            with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
                data= "Name","Score"
                f.write(str(data))



excel_search()
    with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as f:
        f.writerows('\n'[Student_Name],[User_Score]) # have defined userscore and studentname earlier
```

Comment: There's no question or problem statement in your post. What is wrong with that code? What is the current vs. the expected behavior?

Comment: What is the exact question? Btw, your code as a few syntax errors.

Comment: i want it to search the csv file for name and score and if it is in the file then proceed to type in the users score and name underneath the headings whereas if it is not in the csv file then add the headings?

Comment: read all file, do what you need with data, write all file - it is easier.

Comment: could you also write some python using the information i have given u so i can have a more efficient working answer much appreciate any help

Comment: @furas what do u mean could u give me an example with python?

Comment: I've just answered to a related question that can be useful for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722389/check-if-specific-column-in-csv-file-contains-data

Comment: thanks any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are going for but it may work for your purpose.

```
import csv
search=input('Enter string to search: ')
stock=open ('FileName.csv', 'wb')
reader=csv.reader(FileName)
for row in reader:
    for field in row:
        if field==code:
            print('Record found! \n')
            print('Name: '+row[0])
            print('Score: '+row[1])
```

The `print('Name: '+row[0])` should print the name and the `print('Score: '+row[1])` should print the player's score.